# Protobuf.net WCF Deserialize List<T>

Tags: c#, wcf, protobuf-net

I try use WCF with protobuf-net r.282

Ok. I mark my contracts with ProtoBehavior attribute

```
    [OperationContract,ProtoBehavior]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceFaultException))]
    Dictionary<ActivityCategoryDTO, SalesTemplateDTO> GetSalesTemplates();

    [OperationContract, ProtoBehavior]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceFaultException))]
    List<ActivityCategoryDTO> GetActivities();
```

Next, - DTO:

```
    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    [ProtoContract]
    public class ActivityCategoryDTO
    {
        [DataMember]
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string Guid { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I try consume this servise from client. When I call GetSalesTemplates - all is OK. I've got successful deserialized dictionary, but when I call GetActivities I get null at client.
Through fiddler I see that, data is transmitting succesfully, so I think it's deserializer problem.

What's wrong? How can I get List at Client?

**EDIT**

It seems that I have problems with all Lists :)

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class SalesTemplateDTO
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public List<FieldTemplateDTO> Fields;
}
```

It comes to client just with Name, List of Fields is null again. Though all data is transmitted too.

Comment: Hi Andrew - sorry for the delay; lots of "busy" lately. Analysed and explained below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK; I've reproduced and this actually looks to be the IDE/svcutil refusing to re-use the service-contract (interface) from your DTO assembly, even though it is re-using the data-contracts (classes). The mex-generated service-contract (interface) lacks the necessary extra attributes, so protobuf-net **never gets asked to deserialize**.

Two options:

### Option 1

[use configuration rather than code](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/11/controlling-wcf-protobuf-net-at.html) to define the protobuf usage; the advantage of this is that it can be used without any changes to either client *or* server.

### Option 2

don't use the generated service wrapper - a generic counterpart can be written simply as:

```
public class Client<T> : ClientBase<T> where T : class
{
    public T Service { get { return Channel; } }
        public Client() {
    }

    public Client(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }

    public Client(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public Client(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public Client(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }
}
```

Then consume as:

```
using (var svc = new Client<IService1>())
{
    var data = svc.Service.GetActivities();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It works. I follow extension-config way. But now I've got problem with enums..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know off the top of my head; I can investigate, but not right at this moment. As a pragmatic workaround (until I can find why), perhaps return something like a `ActivityResult` class that *contains* a `List<ActivityCategoryDTO>` as a member?

Comment: Unfortumality, this workaround doesn't help and I still haven't decision for this.